# How to read a number from text file via Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 1000 text files and want to read a number from each file.

format of text file as:

```
 af;laskjdf;lkasjda123241234123
$sakdfja;lskfj12352135qadsfasfa
falskdfjqwr1351

##alskgja;lksjgklajs23523,
asdfa#####1217653asl123654fjaksj
 asdkjf23s#q23asjfklj
asko3
```

I need to read the number ("1217653") behind "#####" in each txt file.

The number will follow the "#####" closely in all text file.

"#####" and the close following number just appear one time in each file.

```
clc
clear
MyFolderInfo = dir('yourpath/folder');
fidin = fopen(file_name,'r','n','utf-8');
while ~feof(fidin)
    tline=fgetl(fidin);
    disp(tline)
end
fclose(fidin);
```

It is not finish yet. I am stuck with the problem that it can not read after the space line.

Comment: It would actually help if you showed a **realistic** version of your text file, not a result of you mashing your keyboard with random characters.

Comment: XJ.C, the reason for rayryeng's request is that it's very common that people provide some quick sample data, but when people provide an answer that works for that case they respond: "This doesn't work, because my **actual** data doesn't contain blah blah", or "What I **actually** need is all data behind `#####`, not only numbers. All of us have been burned on this, so we like to make sure the scenario we work with is actually realistic, otherwise it's just a waste of time for everyone involved.

Comment: Also, this question doesn't follow the guidelines in [ask]. Please show us what you have tried, this is not a code writing service =)

Comment: I am try to do it by myself. But I stuck with the problem that the code can not read after the space line.

Comment: @StewieGriffin I just want to read the number behind "#####", say "1217653" on the above sample text.

Comment: Can there be several instances? If so, how do you want to store the results? Can there be several instances on a single line? What about `#####abc123`? Do you want `123` there or not?

Comment: The number will follow "#####" tightly.  So it  won't be happen the format you mention.

Comment: I beleive it is best to use [regex](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to use Regular Expressions. But I can not read those lines after the space line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another approach using the function `regex`. This will easily provide a more advanced way of reading files and does not require reading the full file in one go. The difference from the already given example is basically that I read the file line-by-line, but since the example use this approach I believe it is worth answering. This will return **all** occurences of "#####NUMBER"

```
function test()
h = fopen('myfile.txt');
str = fgetl(h);
k = 1;
while (isempty(str) | str ~= -1 ) % Empty line returns empty string and EOF returns -1
    res{k} = regexp(str,'#####\d+','match');
    k = k+1;
    str = fgetl(h);
end

for k=1:length(res)
    disp(res{k});
end
```

**EDIT**

Using the expression '#####(\d+)' and the argument `'tokens'` instead of `'match'` Will actually return the digits after the "#####" as a string. The intent with this post was also, apart from showing another way to read the file, to show how to use `regexp` with a simple example. Both alternatives can be used with suitable conversion.

Comment: Nice addition! Do you know if reading the file line by line is faster than reading it in one go? Or is the main advantage better memory handling for huge files?

Comment: @Skogsv I do not think this is will be faster. The main advantage is memory. I also believe this can give more flexibility to decide how to write code. It also gives more flexibility to select starting point. In that case you may save time as well. Assume you want to read the middle part of a book. Then the process can be speed up with [`fseek`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) and `fgetl`. The reason I wrote this is however, only because this was used in the Question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following:

- All files are ASCII files.
- The number you are looking to extract is directly following `#####`.
- The number you are looking for is a natural number.
- `#####` followed by a number only occurs once per file.

You can use this code snippet inside a `for` loop to extract each number:

```
regx='#####(\d+)';
str=fileread(fileName);

num=str2double(regexp(str,regx,'tokens','once'));
```

### Example of for loop

This code will iterate through **ALL** files in `yourpath/folder` and save the numbers into `num`.

```
regx='#####(\d+)'; % Create regex

folderDir='yourpath/folder';
files=cellstr(ls(folderDir)); % Find all files in folderDir
files=files(3:end); % remove . and ..

num=zeros(1,length(files)); % Pre allocate

for i=1:length(files) % Iterate through files
str=fileread(fullfile(folderDir,files{i})); % Extract str from file
num(i)=str2double(regexp(str,regx,'tokens','once')); % extract number using regex
end
```

If you want to extract more ''advanced'' numbers e.g. Integers or Real numbers, or handle several occurrences of `#####NUMBER` in a file you will need to update your question with a better representation of your text files.

Comment: Does this give _all_ entries of "#####NBR"?

Comment: It does not, since the question specified that the number only occurs once per file. If more than the first occurrence is wanted, simply remove `'once'` from the `regexp` call. This will however cause `regexp` to return cells meaning some of the code needs to be changed.